# DB2 to SQL migration

Tags: mysql

I want to transfer the data from DB2 tables to SQL server in a c# console application. I have the same schema at both the places I used the code as below

```
        string connectionstring = ("Database = vvv  ; UserID = ggg; Password = jjj");
        string querystring = "select * from Employee" ;

        using (DB2Connection con = new DB2Connection(connectionstring))
        {
            using (DB2Command cmd = new DB2Command((querystring))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                Console.Write("Loading data");
                using (DB2DataAdapter da = new DB2DataAdapter(cmd))
                {


                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Employee");
                    da.Fill(dt);



                    string connection = @"SERVER = something here; uid = sdf; password = fgh; database =ggg;Integrated Security=True";
                        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                        {

                            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
                            }

                            //bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
                            bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 10000;
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Employee";
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                        }

                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }






        }
    }


}
```

It is getting almost 1 to 1.5 hours to load the data from the adapter to dataset

```
da.Fill(dt); ---here
```

Please provide the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Cleaned up the code a little

Comment: Not getting exactly by your comment...Exactly where need to improve?